# Consulta que funciona en SQL y no en PHP

Tags: php, sql

Tengo un código como este:

```
$consulta= "select campo1, campo2, ..
 from tabla 
where fecha >'2017-10-12 9:42' 
order by fecha asc";
echo $consulta; /*lo tengo para hacer pruebas */
$filas = $db->query($consulta);
if (!$filas) {
        $error=$db->errorInfo();
        return "Error en la consulta. Error ". $error[2];
    } else {
        if ($filas->rowcount()==0) echo "<span>No hay resutados</span>";
        else
        foreach($filas as $fila){
                   .................
        }
```

Fecha es de tipo `datetime`.

El tema es que al ejecutar el código en el servidor me da un resultado (ninguna fila) y sin embargo si copio lo que se imprime en el echo (la consulta) y lo ejecuto directamente usando el editor que hay en phpMyAdmin me da el resultado que debiera (en este momento salen 2 filas).

Cuando cambio el símbolo de `>` por `<` (para ver los anteriores a la fecha) ejecutando el php me saca todas las filas. Si pego la consulta lo hace correctamente y sólo saca los eventos anteriores a la fecha.

Este mismo código lo he probado con la función `now()` de SQL en vez de la fecha escrita (mi idea es sacarla con javascript del equipo que utiliza la aplicación) y funciona correctamente. Mi problema es que la hora del servidor es distinta y por lo tanto saca eventos futuros horas después de que ya han pasado.

La pregunta es si a alguien le ha pasado algo similar (una consulta que funcione en SQL y no a través del método `query()` y como lo ha solucionado.

Comment: Agregale los segundos '2017-10-12 09:42:00'

Comment: Tambien tenes que verificar la zona horaria  :  http://php.net/manual/es/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: También usa `mysqli_error()` para revisar el error del mensaje después de ejecutar la consulta. **[Fuente](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22434814/cant-execute-a-sql-query-mysql-php#comment34117413_22434814)**.

Comment: He seguido haciendo pruebas y he visto que el error no está en el código que he puesto. Me ha engañado el hecho de que la consulta se imprime.. El error está en la creación de esa fecha ya que la hago en javascript y me estoy dando cuenta que no se ha creado cuando se ejecuta la consulta (al parecer está comparando con un string vacío), es un problema de tiempos. Seguiré probando por ahí..

Answer (score 0):

He seguido haciendo pruebas y he visto que el error no está en el código que he puesto. Me ha engañado el hecho de que la consulta se imprime.. El error está en la creación de esa fecha ya que la hago en javascript y me estoy dando cuenta que no se ha creado cuando se ejecuta la consulta (al parecer está comparando con un string vacío), es un problema de tiempos. Seguiré probando por ahí..

Answer (score 0):

Si la consulta SQL te devuelve resultados en phpMyAdmin, casi con toda seguridad algo esta mal en la lógica de tu programa. Hacer un debug básico te ayudaría a encontrar facilmente el error, o al menos a ir descartando... Por ejemplo tu código podrías reemplazarlo por algo como:

```
$consulta= "select campo1, campo2, ..
 from tabla 
where fecha >'2017-10-12 9:42' 
order by fecha asc";

echo $consulta; /*lo tengo para hacer pruebas */
$filas = $db->query( $consulta );
var_dump( $filas );
if ( ! $filas) {
    die( "No hay resultados" );

    $error=$db->errorInfo();
    return "Error en la consulta. Error ". $error[2];

} else {
    die( "Hay resultados" );

    if ($filas->rowcount()==0) 
        echo "<span>No hay resutados</span>";
    else
        foreach($filas as $fila){
            ...
        }
```

*PD: perdón, es muy tarde para responder. Se me murió la batería del portátil mientras contestaba hace unas horas...*